# How can I do a subtraction on unary numbers terminated in X on turing machine?

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines

For example, if I have 11X1111X as input, the result should be X. For another example, input: 1111XX -> 1111X. I am a complete beginner and all my tries so far failed to meet the expectation.

This was my latest try:
[image]

Comment: I do not follow your first example - can you please check it?

Comment: @greybeard I think the results is zero whenever the second operand is greater than the first one

Comment: (@melfnt I had noticed you implied this in your answer. I'm not contradicting it. I do not find the first example in this question helpful *as is: without mention how to interpret/handle more $1$s after the first $X$ than before*.)

Comment: @greybeard sure, whatever. Let's wait and see if OP clarifies: I will edit my answer if needed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, notice that if you have to compute $N-M$ you can subtract one from each operand and the result will not change (i.e. $N-M = (N-1) - (M-1)$.

Keeping that in mind, I would remove a 1 from each operand replacing it with another symbol Y just to avoid spaces on the tape, and repeat until either operand "runs out" of ones --that means that either $N$ or $M$ is now zero. When it happens, clean out the tape a little bit: the left operand is the result of the computation.

So, executing this algorithm in your examples:
example 1

```
11X1111X input
Y1XY111X
YYXYY11X notice that the left operand is zero
  X      cleanup
```

example 2

```
1111XX input
Y111XX notice that the right operand is zero
1111X  cleanup
```

As you can see from the second example, if the first operand is bigger than the second you will have to revert the last substitution replacing a Y with a 1.

Another meaningful example:

```
1111111X1111X input
Y111111XY111X
YY11111XYY11X
YYY1111XYYY1X
YYYY111XYYYYX
YYYYY11XYYYYX notice that the right operand is zero
    111X      cleanup
```

As for the actual program, here is just a sketch, try to write it yourself:

- in q0 search for a 1 to replace. That means, skip all the Ys and continue moving right until you find a 1, then don't move and go to q1.
- in q1 replace the 1 with a Y, then move right and go in another state (q2) to reach the other operand.
- in q2, go right until you find an X (that means you have reach the second operand), then move right and go to q0 to remove a 1 from the second operand too.

This part will replace a 1 from both operands (if there are enough ones), the states of the machines are q0 -> q1 -> q2 -> q0 -> q1 -> q2.

At this point the scanner is placed at the end of the input string, you realize it when you find an empty cell in q2, so;

- in q2, if you find an empty cell, move left and go to q3 (which will move the scanner at the beginning of the input).
- in q3 move left ignoring any character until you find an empty cell. That means you have reached the beginning of the string. Move right and go to q0.

This loop continues until either operand runs out of 1s. You realize it when you find an X in q0, so:

- in q0 if you find an X, move right and go to q4 that is the state that initializes the cleanup part
- in q4 move right ignoring any character until you find an empty cell, that means you have reached end of the input, move left and go to q5 to perform the cleanup phase.

Complete the program as an exercise: if you want you can edit this answer to add the sketch of the cleanup phase.

Comment: I do understand your examples, but I don't know how I can translate that into my code (http://turingmachine.io/ format). Do I make my ones into Y in of my states?

Comment: @TalionZz I'll update my answer but I can't write the whole program for you otherwise you won't learn the turing machine -- I suppose this is a homework, right?

Comment: it is an optional exercise that my teacher recommended, it isn't a due assignment. I just thought that knowing how to do it would be better for me.

Comment: @TalionZz sure it will, but you have to think by yourself otherwise you won't learn. I think you should start over with your program: I added a sketch of the algorthm, try and translate it into your language. The cleanup phase is an exercise (:

Comment: @melfntI followed your instruction but I'm stuck when it comes to q3, the head stops in the empty cell as you said, but I can't get to move it to the left. This is my code so far: input: 'Y111111XY111X' 
blank: ' '

start state: q0
table:
  q0:
    'Y': {R: q1}
  q1:
    1: {write: 'Y', R: q2}
  q2:
    1: R
    'X': {R: q0}
    ' ': {L: q3}
  q3:
    [1, 'X', 'Y']: L how can I make it back to the far left ?

Comment: @TalionZz your code for q0 is wrong, because it has to go to q1 only when it reads a 1. There is nothing wrong with your rules for the state q3, the problem is that you are expecting the head to be on the rightmost cell of the input when the state is q3, but it is actually on the first blank cell after the input. So you have to fix the transition from q2 to q3.

Comment: I made it go back to where it started, but now  for some reason it jumps the first 1 and turns the next one to Y on both of the operands. It goes from: Y111111XY111X to Y1YY1XY1YYX and it stops @melfnt this is my code:   q0:
    'Y': R
    1: {R: q1}
    ' ': {L: q3}
  q1:
    1: {write: 'Y', R: q2}
    'Y': R
  q2:
    1: R
    'X': {R: q0}
    ' ': {L: q3}
  q3:
    [1, 'X', 'Y']: L
    ' ': {R: q0}

Comment: @TalionZz I see the problem but I won't tell you what is it, you have to do it by yourself. Run the machine step-by-step and be careful to spot when it behaves differently from what you would expect: the last used rule is wrong. Notice (1) the state in which the machine is and (2) the current cell. If the first is wrong, you have to fix the next-state part of the last used rule, if the latter is wrong you have to fix the direction part of the last used rule

Comment: Anyway, the comments [are not meant for extended discussion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), we should move to chat.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to chat, I haven't stopped trying all day to make it work and yet it still doesn't. I manage to get one example to work with Y111XX has input with 1111X has a result, but the other examples still wouldn't work.This is my current progress [link] https://www.noelshack.com/2020-51-2-1608053012-sans-titre.jpg [/link] @melfnt

Comment: @talionZz I don't understand your "input" part: the input should contain only 1s and 2 Xs, not Ys. Anyway I would have simplified the rules a little bit: when you find a blank cell in q3 you can just move right and go to q0. When you find an X in q0 you are done: move to the end of the input and clean up. Have you tried to figure out what the machine has to do in the ceanup phase? Could you describe it by words?

Comment: I would suppose that the cleanup phase is meant to have only the 1s and the last X left on the tape and nothing else. So that everything on the right of the result needs to be wiped out.

Comment: @talionZz sure, go on and program it.

Comment: I managed to make my program work for 1111X11X [link] https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/51/3/1608130329-1111x11x.png [/link] and 1111XX [link] https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/51/3/1608130330-1111x.jpg [/link] but I can'tget to make it work for 11X1111X...

Comment: @TalionZz You should make a single program that works for every input, that's precisely the definition of programming... If you can't get it work when the first operand is smaller than the second it's because that's a particular case: how can the machine realize it? I mean: in which state and reading what? What do you have to do in that case? Try to explain it by words and then to write the actual rules but remember: **you have to write a single program that works on every input**. Also, [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) you find correct markdown syntax for inline hyperlinks

Comment: Well I might just give up on this, I spent too much time already and I can't afford any more hours. I major in foreign languages and thought taking this "basic computer science" class would be a good idea but I guess my non-existent logic in maths for the past 4 years can't adapt. Thanks for your help !

Comment: No, please, don't give up now! You are making progress, you just have to think longer before you write your code: programming is a lot about thinking, not typing. Focus on how would you solve this problem at higher level, then the programming phase will be easier! Try and describe by words what should the machine do after one operand becomes zero, I will help you!

Comment: Here I am still trying even though I have actual assignment to finish. Could please just tell me how many states in total I should have ? I have 8 right now and I still can't get to make it work for all the inputs, the 11X1111X keeps me struggling with 1X as output...

Comment: @TalionZz glad to hear that you didn't give up! I don't think that the total number of states is an useful information. Anyway, I can solve this problem with a Turing machine that have exactly 8 states, but you can use more, it's not a problem! Regarding your specific issue: when the first operand is smaller you replaced a extra one, which you have to rewrite at the end of the cleanup phase (so in your example the correct output is 11X). How can the machine realize that the first operand is smaller? I mean: in which state and reading which symbol?

Comment: @TalionZz I'm sure you know that CSSE's comments is not the right place for discussion, maybe you can reach me in other ways? You can find my contacts in my profile.